# Groups and multiply both sides.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, proof-explanation

I'm just starting to learn group theory by reading "Abstract Algebra" by Dummit and Foote. Apologies if this question is stupid, I don't have a very strong background in mathematics. I'm trying to prove the very early propositions to myself (specifically, Proposition 1, number 4 on page 18: $(a * b)^{-1} = (b^{-1}) * (a^{-1})$).

After struggling for a little while I decided to check the solution, and was surprised to see it uses the technique of "multiplying on both sides". Why is this legitimate? Do we not need to know that $*$ is injective before we can do this? In other words, it may be obvious that $a = b \implies a * c = b * c$, but how do we know that the reverse implication is true?

Comment: The reverse implication is just "multiply on both sides" using $c^{-1}$. This crucially requires the existence of inverses. There are cases where it's not true, for example when your algebraic structure has [zero divisors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero_divisor). This will always work for groups though.

Comment: We don't need to multiply on both sides. All we need to do is to check that $(ab)(b^{-1}a^{-1})=e$ and then maybe, depending on what we have proved already, that $(b^{-1}a^{-1})(ab)=e$. The calculation just uses associativity and defining facts about inverse.

Comment: They really do use the fact that $x = y \implies c*x = c*y$. In the book, it's left-multiplication of an equation by $a^{-1}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We know that

$$
a * c = b * c \implies a = b
$$
by multiplying with $c^{-1}$ on both sides. This requires the existence of $c^{-1}$ for every $c$, which is guaranteed to us by the group axioms.

There are algebraic structures known as rings where the existence of multiplicative inverses need not hold. A simple example is to consider $\mathbb{Z}$, and ask for the multiplicative inverse of $2$. Since this does not exist, $(\mathbb{Z}, \times)$ cannot be a group.

Comment: Thankyou. I was so fixated on this being an issue and assumed it was not true in general that I didn't even try the (simple) proof.